# Write a relatively simple, recursive claim in arithmetic which is equivalent to Tarski's indefinability of truth

Tags: logic, stopping-times, incompleteness

> Write a relatively simple, recursive claim in arithmetic which is equivalent to defining truth.

For example:  Define $f(x):\Bbb{N}\to\Bbb{N}$ such that if we set:

$x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$

Then any proof of the claim:

$\forall x\in\Bbb{N}, \exists m\in\Bbb{N}:x_m=1$

would break Tarski's indefinability of truth.

---

Okay, in response to Gerry's comment I'm expanding the background behind this question; perhaps against my better judgement; but here it is...  The Collatz graph is closely related to iteration of the left and right transforms $T_L(x)=2x-1$ and $T_R(x)=2x+1$ on the odd integers.

Now these transforms on iteration are sufficient to construct every odd integer from the number $1$.  Furthermore if we use the very similar transforms $T_{L2}(x)=x-2^{v_2(x)-1}$ and $T_{L2}(x)=x+2^{v_2(x)+1}$ we can construct the dyadic rationals modulo $1$ from the starting integer $0$ - in fact this generates both the positive and negative dyadic rationals modulo $\pm1$, i.e. $\pm1\times\Bbb{Z}(2^{\infty})$.  Now it turns out the Collatz conjecture has a natural extension which is situated in the Prufer 2-group $\Bbb{Z}(2^{\infty})$, and this also reflects perfectly into $-\Bbb{Z}(2^{\infty})$

So the question I'm left asking myself, when I wonder what provability theory says about Collatz conjecture, is whether this iterative process of constructing the integers from $1$ "looks like" in a "homotopy type theory" sense, some theorem which states that its own solution is impossible.

My curiosity is further piqued by a) this process is an infinitely recursive process and b) Proof of the Collatz conjecture seems to rely on the the failure of the Prufer 2-group to be Noetherian.  This puts the "final set" of odd integers beyond reach in a special way which renders the entire Collatz graph **incomplete** without the "final set".  So there is a sense in which recursion can never get you to a proof - which I'm interpreting as saying; you need to transcend recursion and consider the overall properties of the Prufer 2-group.  And again, I see similarities with what little I know of provability theory; namely the fact that a diagonal argument is used which could be analogous to the Prufer 2-group not being noetherian.

Trouble is; while I know the Collatz Conjecture intimately, knowing much about provability and decidability is a million miles away for me right now.  But if I can "see" what such a recursive process looks like in an unprovability/undecidability proof I might recognise which, if any, of the objects in it might correspond to the thing I'm studying, and how the "not attainable by recursion" problem (or more precisely; $\Phi(\Bbb{Z}(2^{\infty}))=\Bbb{Z}(2^{\infty})$ where $\Phi$ is the Frattini Subgroup and recursion is the repeated application of some map from the smallest subgroup containing $x$ to an element strictly of some supergroup thereof) may have been overcome elsewhere.

Comment: Have you read Conway's paper on the undecidability of Collatz-like questions?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm aware of it and the result that there are undecidable Collatz-like problems but I fear it may be too technical for me. Perhaps MSE has a place for a dumbed-down explanation?

Comment: Or perhaps a dumbed-down explanation is impossible, and you'll have to actually learn some math to understand. But why give up on the Conway paper when you haven't even looked at it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have studied and understood many complex things and one thing connects them all.  There is ALWAYS a dumbed-down explanation.

Comment: @GerryMyerson ... and obviously I wouldn't easily give up without looking at it.  Having found Kurtz & Simon's follow-up to Conway I spent some time researching what $\Pi_2$-complete meant &after a few hours and blank searches on MSE I was able to find this describes the complexity class. Reading about Complexity classes I found some fairly complex material which requires a substantial amount of learning to even begin to comprehend but which I could get the general gist of; so I could see with a few hundred hours work I might approach a rigorous understanding of the paper's first paragraph.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're making a bit of a category error. The undefinability of truth is **not** about proofs at all, or indeed any axiomatic system in any way: it's about the **structure** $\mathcal{N}=(\mathbb{N}; +,\times,0,1)$. Specifically, any formula $\varphi(x)$ in one variable in the language of arithmetic defines the set $$\varphi^\mathcal{N}=\{n\in\mathbb{N}: \mathcal{N}\models\varphi(n)\}.$$ Tarski's theorem says that the set $TA$ of Godel numbers of sentences true in $\mathcal{N}$ is not definable; that is, $$TA\not=\varphi^\mathcal{N}$$ for any one-variable formula $\varphi$ in the language of arithmetic.

Note that there is no "background theory" here; Tarski's theorem says something about the *complexity* of a particular set of natural numbers. In purely computability-theoretic language, Tarski's theorem says $$\mbox{For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have }TA\not\le_T {\bf 0^{(n)}}.$$

---

Now what you're asking for essentially is a situation where a *proof* of a sentence $\psi$ would yield a *definition* of a particular set of natural numbers. But this isn't really a thing that happens. In fact, there's a clear mismatch here: a proof takes place within an axiom system, whereas a definition takes place inside a structure, and our structure isn't changing here (it's just $\mathcal{N}$).

In general, the existence of a *proof of a statement from a theory* doesn't give you a *definition of a set in a structure*; they're just different kinds of objects. Of course, a proof of a statement from a theory *can* tell you that the theory *proves some important fact about* a definition, but that definition was (if it existed at all) pre-existing. So the point is that there's no real way to leverage Tarski's theorem to do the sort of thing you want it to.

In principle, the following could occur:

- You have some sort of object you want to prove doesn't exist.
- You show that if such an object does exist, then there is a *definable* such object.
- You show that *relative to* any such object, you can define truth.
- Combining the second and third bulletpoints above and using Tarski's theorem, we've accomplished the goal set out in the first bulletpoint.

I am, however, not aware of a single case where this approach has been used successfully (well, I can cook up a couple artificial ones, but they are better solved with other means anyways).

Comment: Thanks @Noah very helpful as always. "what (I'm) asking for essentially is a situation where a proof of a sentence ψ would yield a definition of a particular set of natural numbers. But this isn't really a thing that happens"... Perhaps I imagined that Godel numbering could equate some sequence of true formulae in a proof with a sequence of unique numbers. So is there some statement, whose proof requires a sequence of Godel numbers such that completion of the theorem is not in $\mathcal{N}$?  Note that the requirement that Godel numbers be ordered by implication affects the number available.

Comment: by "ordered by implication" I mean if $S_1\land S_2\implies S_4$ then the proof would require an ordered sequence $1,2,4$; not just the set $\{1,2,4\}$. Maybe the ordering is such that to prove $S_{\aleph_0}$ we require $S_{\aleph_2}$ first.  This is a bit like what $\Phi(\Bbb{Z}(2^{\infty}))=\Bbb{Z}(2^{\infty})$ looks like.